# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar este algoritmo?

Tags: python, optimización

Sumará 1 si algun valor de A se encuentra en N
Restará en 1 si algun valor de B se encuentra en N

El código funciona pero me gustaría que fuera más optimo.

```
def run(j,n, a,b):
    happines = 0
    j =j.split('')
    n=n.split()
    for i in range(0,int(j[0])):
        happines+=(1 if n[i] in a else -1 if n[i] in b else 0 )
    print(happines)
```

En las variables puedo recibir otros valores aleatorios pero este solo es un ejemplo

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    j = ("100000 47478") #[0] tamaño del arreglo N, [1] tamaño del arreglo A y B
    # Son mas numeros pero con estos son suficientes    
    n = ("99938099 99939500 99628901 99795484 99600395") 
    a = ("99500003 99500012 99500022 99500029 99500039 99500054")
    b = ("99999991 99999971 99999967 99999959 99999957 99999932")
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Es necesario agregar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder ayudarte. Al copiar y pegar tu código y utilizando los valores de `j`. `n`, `a` y `b` que pones no funciona

Comment: ¿qué quieres decir con optimo? ¿más rápido? ¿más corto? ¿más legible?

Comment: optimizar en que aspecto? memoria? tiempo de ejecución promedio? uso de un solo procesador? uso de múltiples procesadores? tiempo que toma leer el código fuente? tiempo en que toma mantener el código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si por optimización te refieres a la velocidad de ejecución, la última palabra la tiene siempre la medida de tiempos. Usando el módulo `timeit` se pueden comparar tres alternativas:

1. La tuya original. Es una alternativa muy cercana al óptimo, puesto que recorres la lista `n` una sola vez. No obstante el uso de la expresión ternaria `happines += (expresion ternaria)` está forzando a hacer una suma en cada iteración, ya sea para sumar 1, sumar -1, o sumar 0. En realidad sumar 0 no era necesario por lo que hay ahí una oportunidad de optimización.
2. La que propone Candid Moe. Esta solución utiliza comprensiones de listas o expresiones generadoras, que tienen fama de ser mucho más rápidas que los bucles explícitos. Bien, esto no es del todo cierto. Son más rápidas cuando el objetivo es crear una lista, pero no necesariamente cuando el objetivo sea procesar datos y generar un resultado que no sea una lista. Habrá que cronometrar para ver si realmente se gana algo. Además esta solución presenta una ineficiencia y es que la lista se está recorriendo dos veces, una para encontrar todos los casos en que el número esté en `a` y una segunda para encontrar todos los casos en que el número esté en `b`, para luego restar ambos contadores. Es bastante probable que aún si la comprensión habría hecho ganar algo de tiempo, la duplicación del recorrido haga perder esa ganancia.
3. La solución que voy a proponer yo, basandome en la tuya original, pero evitando sumar los ceros.

La tercera solución propuesta parece a primera vista más ineficiente, ya que no usa comprensiones de listas ni expresiones generadoras, y además el código es más largo y tiene unos feos `if`/`elif`, no obstante la última palabra la tiene la toma de mediciones.

Este es mi código:

```
happines = 0
# j = j.split()  # No necesitamos j pues iteramos directamente por n
n = n.split()
for num in n:
  if num in a:
    happines += 1
  elif num in b:
    happines -=1
```

### Toma de tiempos

Para referencia, estas son las soluciones contendientes, implementadas como funciones y quitando los `print()` que introducirían tiempos adicionales, cambiándolos por `return`:

La solución original del OP:

```
def run_0(j,n, a,b):
    happines = 0
    j =j.split()
    n=n.split()
    for i in range(0,int(j[0])):
        happines+=(1 if n[i] in a else -1 if n[i] in b else 0 )
    return happines
```

Las dos soluciones propueas por Candid Moe (una con listas, otra con expresiones generadoras):

```
def run_1(j, n, a, b):
    ns = n.split()
    a1 = a.split()
    b1 = b.split()
    an = [x for x in ns if x in a1]
    bn = [x for x in ns if x in b1]
    happines =  len(an) - len(bn)
    return happines

def run_2(j, n, a, b):
    ns = n.split()
    a1 = a.split()
    b1 = b.split()
    happines =  sum(1 for x in ns if x in a1) - sum(1 for x in ns if x in b1)
    return happines
```

Mi solución

```
def run_3(j, n, a, b):
    happines = 0
    # j = j.split()
    n = n.split()
    for num in n:
      if num in a:
        happines += 1
      if num in b:
        happines -=1
    return happines
```

Este sería el código que las cronometra, usando como datos de entrada los proporcionados en la pregunta (hay que cambiar `j` para que contenga correctamente el número de elementos de las otras dos)

```
import timeit

j = ("5 6")  
n = ("99938099 99939500 99628901 99795484 99600395") 
a = ("99500003 99500012 99500022 99500029 99500039 99500054")
b = ("99999991 99999971 99999967 99999959 99999957 99999932")
for caso in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4):
  func = f"run_{caso}(j, n, a, b)"
  t = timeit.timeit(func, number=1000, globals=globals())
  print(f"run_{caso}: {t*1000} µs")
```

Y los resultados son... (drumroll):

```
run_0: 3.5900520015275106 µs
run_1: 6.095775999710895 µs
run_2: 6.415276999177877 µs
run_3: 1.96833600057289 µs
```

Moraleja. Si la métrica de optimización es el tiempo, hay que medirlo y no confiar en la intuición.

## Ampliación de la respuesta. Optimización adicional

Cualquiera de las soluciones cronometradas necesita mirar si un dato concreto está en `a` y si está en `b`. Para ello utilizan una expresión del estilo `x in a`. Esto causa que el intérprete recorra la lista `a` comparando cada elemento con `x` para retornar `True` tan pronto como encuentre una coincidencia. En el peor caso en que no haya coincidencias necesitará recorrer la lista entera.

Esto puede ser una fuente de ineficiencia muy grande si las listas `a` o `b` son muy largas. De hecho, tu ejemplo sugiere que sí que son muy largas pues según los valores dados a `j` tendrían 47478 elementos.

Un tipo de datos más adecuado para albergar `a` y `b` sería un **conjunto** (`set`). Este tipo de datos también permite mirar si contienen o no un elemento (`if elem in conjunto`), pero por la forma en que están implementados internamente el intérprete no necesita recorrer el conjunto entero para decidir si el elemento está o no está. La respuesta `True` o `False` se obtiene con una sola operación.

Usando notación matemática diríamos que `valor in lista` tiene una complejidad O(N), mientras que `valor in conjunto` tiene una complejidad O(1). Esto quiere decir que cuanto mayor sea la lista, más tiempo tardará la operación `valor in lista`, mientras que en el conjunto por el contrario lo que se tarda no depende del tamaño del conjunto, se tarda lo mismo en conjuntos pequeños que en grandes.

Así pues podemos implementar una cuarta solución que convierta `a` y `b` en conjuntos antes de entrar al bucle que computa `hapiness`:

```
def run_4(j, n, a, b):
    happines = 0
    # j = j.split()
    n = n.split()
    a = set(a.split())
    b = set(b.split())
    for num in n:
      if num in a:
        happines += 1
      if num in b:
        happines -=1
    return happines
```

Si cronometramos esta solución con los datos del enunciado obtenemos que no hemos mejorado tiempos. De hecho ¡los hemos empeorado! El tiempo que requiere esta solución es de 4.886 µs, mayor incluso que tu código original (pero menor todavía que las soluciones con comprensiones de listas).

La razón es que la conversión de `a` y `b` en conjuntos requiere también su tiempo, y en este ejemplo en el que las listas son tan pequeñas, el tiempo extra invertido en convertirlas en conjuntos no compensa la mínima ganancia de tiempo que se tendrá luego con el operador `in` (pues éste será de todas formas muy rápido sobre las listas al ser éstas tan pequeñas).

Cabe suponer que para un número elevado de elementos en las listas `a` y `b` el método con conjuntos sería más rápido.

Comment: Woaaah, me falta mucho por aprender. Gracias de verdad, me sirvió!!! 

Answer (score 0):

En Python la opción menos preferible es hacer `for` o `while` para recorrer y procesar listas. La opción preferida es usar *comprensión de listas*, cuya implementación hace más rápida las operaciones.

Una solución es:

```
j = ("100000 47478") #[0] tamaño del arreglo N, [1] tamaño del arreglo A y B
# Son mas numeros pero con estos son suficientes
n = ("99938099 99939500 99628901 99795484 99600395")
a = ("99500003 99500012 99500022 99500029 99500039 99500054")
b = ("99999991 99999971 99999967 99999959 99999957 99999932")

ns = n.split()
a1 = a.split()
b1 = b.split()
an = [x for x in ns if x in a1]
bn = [x for x in ns if x in b1]
happines =  len(an) - len(bn)
print(happines)
```

Primero tomamos las cadenas y las convertimos en listas de valores usando `split`.

La comprensión `[x for x in ns if x in a1]` es la forma abreviada de escribir

```
an = []
for x in ns:
    if x in a1:
        an.append(x)
```

No sólo es escribir menos, es mucho más rápido.

Entonces, `an` contiene todos los valores de `n` que están en `a`, y lo mismo con `nb`.

El total de elementos en ambas listas me da la suma de los +1 y -1 pedida.

#### Segunda optimización

Si bien la solución anterior es más rápida, aún presenta el problema del consumo de memoria, ya que hay que generar dos listas, `an` y `bn` intermedias.

En lugar de *comprensión de listas* se puede usar una *expresión generadora*, que es básicamente la misma comprensión sin los `[]`. Funciona casi igual que una comprensión, excepto que en lugar de retornar la lista completa, devuelve un elemento a la vez cuando se le pide.

Ahora,

```
len(x for x in ns if x in a1)
```

no funciona, pues `len` necesita tener la lista completa para computar el largo.

En lugar de `len`, vamos a usar `sum`, pero reemplazando la expresión generadora para que produzca un `1` por cada elemento aceptado:

```
an = sum(1 for x in ns if x in a1)
```

**Demo**

```
n = ("2 4 5 8 9")
a = ("2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16")
b = ("1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15")
ns = n.split()
a1 = a.split()
b1 = b.split()
happines =  sum(1 for x in ns if x in a1) - sum(1 for x in ns if x in b1)
print(happines)
```

produce:

```
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Increíble! Mil gracias, me sirvió!!